# Pug/Jade: Typeahead.js breaks css of entire form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pug, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I got some problems implementing typeahead.js

Current setup:

- I use Bootstrap v.3.3.7
- I implemented jQuery 3.2
- I downloaded the `typeahead.bundle.min.js` v.0.11.1 from Github
- I added the JS file to my project and linked it on the
- I implemented the typeahead stuff as described in their docs [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#usage)
- I added (an empty CSS) class named `.typeahead` to init the JS stuff

NOTE: All the typeahead stuff (live-search) works great, but typeahead destroys my css.

-

My working Pug/Jade searchbar:

```
.flipkart-navbar-search.smallsearch.col-xs-12.qSearchBar(style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:15px;")
    .row
        input.flipkart-navbar-input.col-xs-11(type='text' id="searchInput" placeholder='Übungen suchen...' autofocus)
        button.flipkart-navbar-button.col-xs-1
            svg(width='15px' height='15px' fill="white")
                path(d='.....')
```

Result:

[image]

-

The code, when I add the .typeahead class to let it init typeahead (also gave it some random other names, the classname is not relevant):

```
.flipkart-navbar-search.smallsearch.col-xs-12.qSearchBar(style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:15px;")
    .row
        input.flipkart-navbar-input.col-xs-11(type='text' id="searchInput" placeholder='Übungen suchen...' autofocus).typeahead
        button.flipkart-navbar-button.col-xs-1
            svg(width='15px' height='15px' fill="white")
                path(d='.....')
```

Results in:

[image]

-

Why is that? I mean of course typeahead brings its own classes like `tt-hint` e.g. to display the results - but these aren't any problem. Why does typeahead actually make my searchbar look like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because like most JS/jQuery plugins, typeahead.js also modifies the DOM structure of the elements that it works on.

So, the updated DOM after initialisation of typeahead would not be the same as what you wrote in your html or jade. Your existing CSS rules may or may not apply to this new DOM structure as intended now.

## Solution

You need to update your CSS rules, so they target the updated DOM after initialisation of `typeahead.js`.

To view the updated DOM, you can use `inspect element` feature of browsers or `developer tools` etc to view the DOM structure in real time.